# What's the functioning scope of an critical section locker in c++?

Tags: c++, locking, critical-section

```
// locks a critical section, and unlocks it automatically
// when the lock goes out of scope
CAutoLock(CCritSec * plock)
```

The above is from `wxutil.h`, does it lock the access of different process , or just locks different threads in the same process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just across threads. From the doc of [CAutoLock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318631.aspx):

> The **CAutoLock** constructor locks the critical section, ...

and [CCritSec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd368963.aspx):

> The **CCritSec** class provides a thread lock.

More explicitly, from the description of [Critical Section Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682530.aspx):

> A *critical section* object provides synchronization similar to that provided by a mutex object, except that a critical section **can be used only by the threads of a single process**.